# Group by table name desc not working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to work on simple messaging system. It is a page which contains the last message sent by each user. This is my table

-message

```
id person1 person2 message  mess_date
1  2       q       hii      2016-07-11 00:00:00.000000
2  q       2       hello    2016-07-10 00:00:00.000000
3  2       q       how r u  2016-07-12 00:00:00.000000
4  2       1       message  2016-07-10 00:00:00.000000
5  q       2       nooooo   2016-07-13 00:00:00.000000
```

-login

```
id roll
1  q
2  1
3  2
```

Now I'm trying to fetch messages using this query --

```
suppose $roll="2";
select login.roll as userid, m1.id, m1.message, m1.mess_date 
from message as m1,login 
where (
    (m1.person1=? and login.roll=m1.person2) or 
    (m1.person2=? and login.roll=m1.person1)
) 
group by login.roll 
order by m1.mess_date desc');
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $roll, $roll);
```

the output has 2 results :

```
q - hiii - 2016-07-11 00:00:00.000000
1 - message - 2016-07-10 00:00:00.000000
```

But I want it to be ordered by mess_date i.e.,

```
q - nooooo - 2016-07-13 00:00:00.000000
1 - message - 2016-07-10 00:00:00.000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL group is not used properly, try the following:

Assume id always growing by time, otherwise you need to do via max(mess_date):

```
SELECT msg1.*
FROM (
    SELECT login.roll AS userid, m1.id, m1.message, m1.mess_date 
    FROM message AS m1,login 
    WHERE (
        (m1.person1=? AND login.roll=m1.person2) OR
        (m1.person2=? AND login.roll=m1.person1)
    )
) AS msg1, (
    SELECT msg.userid, max(msg.id) AS maxid
    FROM (
        SELECT login.roll AS userid, m1.id, m1.message, m1.mess_date 
        FROM message AS m1,login 
        WHERE (
            (m1.person1=? AND login.roll=m1.person2) OR
            (m1.person2=? AND login.roll=m1.person1)
        )
    ) AS msg
    GROUP BY userid
) AS msg2
WHERE msg1.userid = msg2.userid
AND msg1.id = msg2.maxid
ORDER BY msg1.mess_date DESC

$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $roll, $roll, $roll, $roll);
```